# How do I put right-hand side navigation bar without hiding scrollbar?

Tags: css

Consider the following page: http://www5.atpages.jp/~syockit/testFixed.html

I'm creating a page with a header, a footer, and a middle container having left and right navigation bars and a content area in the middle. The thing is, I want the scrollbar for the content to be on right of the window, as opposed to the right of the content area (so that it may follow Fitt's Law in maximized mode). With the current styling, the right navbar is covering the scrollbar, making it not visible.

I noticed that the navbar will move to the left if scrollbar for the whole page (i.e. for `<body>`) is enabled instead. So one solution would be to use `<iframe>` for the content. But is there any way to make the right navbar move to the left to accommodate the scrollbar when it's needed without resorting to iframe?

See www5.atpages.jp/~syockit/testIframe.html for example using iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Your div#content is expanding to the right, you must change:
this

```
#content {
   padding-right: 150px
}
```

to this

```
#content {
  margin-right: 150px;
}
```

Comment: No, that will cause the scrollbar to appear in the middle. What I want is for the scrollbar to be on the edge of the window.

See http://www5.atpages.jp/~syockit/testIframe.html for example using iframe.

Comment: Then move the div#right 15 pixel to the left
#right {
  right: 15px;
}

Answer (score 0):

Yay, after experimenting a bit more, I've finally found an answer! Tested to work on Chrome 11, Firefox 4, Opera 11.

The CSS:

```
.middle { position: absolute; left: 120px; overflow: auto; }
.content { padding-right: 150px; }
.middle, .right-sidebar { top: 100px; bottom: 50px; }
.right-outer { float: right; }
.right-sidebar { position: fixed;}
.right-outer, .right-sidebar {  width: 150px; }
```

The HTML:

```
<div class='middle'>
  <div class='right-outer'>
    <div class='right-sidebar'>
      Sidebar content goes here.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='content'>
  Content goes here.
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see the working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/b4kPm/2/

EDIT: Oops, it didn't work in Opera 11! I wonder what went wrong...

EDIT 2: Opera's absolute positioning will not consider scrollbars. Had to use `float: right`.

EDIT 3: As I thought… It won't automatically readjust when content is dynamically changed to not have overflowing content. This will work only on page load or content re-rendering.